# Can someone please tell me where am I wrong in this python code?

Tags: python, pygame

Here's a simple pygame code where I inserted a screen, a pink rectangle and tried moving it.
The rectangle in the pygame window isn't moving.
Which means the code inside '**' isn't working.
How do I solve that?

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600

pink = (244,133,227)

player_pos = [400, 300]
player_size = 50

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

game_over = False

while not game_over:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

**      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            x = player_pos[0]
            y = player_pos[1]
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= player_size
            elif event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += player_size
            player_pos = [x, y]
    screen.fill((0,0,0))  **

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pink, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], player_size, player_size))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Try adding: 
```python
from pygame import *
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the internals of pygame, but is it even possible for event.type to simultaneously equal pygame.KEYDOWN AND pygame.K_LEFT or K_RIGHT? Could there be another value that contains those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is stored  in the  `key` attribute, rather then the `type` attribute. See [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html):

<s>`if event.type== pygame.K_LEFT:`</s>

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
```

---

See the example:

```py
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600
pink = (244,133,227)
player_pos = [400, 300]
player_size = 50
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

game_over = False
while not game_over:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            x = player_pos[0]
            y = player_pos[1]
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= player_size
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += player_size
            player_pos = [x, y]

    screen.fill((0,0,0))  
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pink, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], player_size, player_size))
    pygame.display.update()
```